# Scala - Slick Database Query

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, scala, playframework

Soy nuevo en esto de Scala con la librería Slick de microservicios, de Scala he trabajado con la librería Spark la cual es directa para llevar sentencias SQL a código Scala y me ha parecido muy difícil entender Slick. Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo 4 métodos que van a usar prácticamente la misma sentencia SQL.

Método Uno (`getListOne(QueryToJoin: ??): List[String`]) usará la sentencia:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tr.trx_cashier) FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')
```

Método dos (`getListTwo(QueryToJoin: ??): List[Int]`) usará la sentencia:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tr.trxpaymethodid) FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')
```

Método tres (`getAllTrxs(QueryToJoin: ?): Future[Seq(Trx)]?`) usará la sentencia:

```
SELECT tr.* FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')
```

Método cuatro (`getAllTrxs(QueryToJoin: ?, DTOLists): Future[Seq(Trx)]?`) usará la sentencia:

```
SELECT tr.* FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')
AND tr.trx_cashier IN (...DTOLists.ListOne...) AND tr.trxpaymethodid IN (...DTOLists.Listtwo...)
```

Como se puede observar todas usan la parte de la sentencia:

```
SELECT ts.* FROM (
    SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
    WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open'
```

Para cada método y no quiero escribir cuatro métodos con prácticamente la misma sentencia SQL, aún no he encontrado la forma de escribir la sentencia anterior en Scala con Slick.

EL siguiente es el diagrama con las clases y las relaciones que he construido hasta el momento:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11lAqxd7JNUBtv4LgnDYmjKiHzmHqEP8t/view?usp=sharing

El código de mis clases de acuerdo al diagrama es:

La clase `TrxService` la cual es la única que debería acceder a la clase `TrxRepository`:

```
class TrxService @Inject()(
    trxRepository: TrxRepository, trxStateService: TrxStateService
)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

  def getListsOne()(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext):
  Future[DTOLists] = {
    val trxState = trxStateService.getAllTrxState()
    DTOLists(
      transactionRepository.getListOne(trxState),
      transactionRepository.getListTwo(trxState)
    )
  }
}
```

La clase `TrxStateService` La cual es la única que debería acceder a la clase `TrxStateRepository`:

```
class TrxStateService @Inject()(trxStateRepository: TrxStateRepository) {

  def getAllTrxState()(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext)
  : Future[Seq[TrxState]] = {
    trxStateRepository.getAllTrxState()
  }
}
```

La clase `TrxRepository` la cual es la única que se supone que debe acceder a la data de la base de datos para la tabla `TrxRepo`

```
@Singleton
class TrxRepository @Inject()(override val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit override val ec: ExecutionContext)
extends BaseRepository[Transaction]
with QrApplicationErrorHandler
with Logging {

  private val trxs = TableQuery[TrxTable]

  def getAllTxByLists(dtoLists: DTOLists)
  (implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext): Future[Seq[Transaction]] = {
    db.run(
      trxs.filter(trxs => trx.terminalNumber == dtoLists.listOne)
        .filter(trxs => trx.paymentMethodId == dtoLists.listTwo).result
    )
  }

  def getAllTrx(trxState: Seq[TrxState])(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext): Future[Seq[Transaction]] = {
    val query = sql"""SELECT tr.* FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
    ) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')""".as[Seq[Transaction]]
    db.run(query)
  }

  def getListOne(trxState: Seq[TrxState])(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
    /*db.run(
      trxs.join(trxState).on(_.trxId = _.trxId)
      .filter(trx => trx.trxType === "sell" || trx.trxType === "refund").map(_.trxCashier)
      .result
      .map(_.toList)
    )
    */
    db.run(sql"""SELECT tr.trx_cashier FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
    ) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')""".as(Seq[Int])
    )
  }

  def getListTwo(trxState: Seq[TrxState])(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
    /*db.run(
      trxs.join(trxState).on(_.trxId = _.trxId)
      .filter(trx => trx.trxType === "sell" || trx.trxType === "refund").map(_.trxCashier)
      .result
      .map(_.toList)
    )
    */
    db.run(sql"""SELECT tr.trxpaymethodid FROM trxRepo tr JOIN (
    SELECT ts.* FROM (
        SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
        WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open' 
    ) trs ON (tr.trx_id = trs.trx_id) WHERE trx_type IN ('sell', 'refund')""".as(Seq[String])
    )
  }

  private class TrxTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Trx](tag, "TrxRepo") {

    def trxId = column[Long]("trx_id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def trxType = column[String]("trx_type")
    def trxPatMethodId = column[Int]("trxpaymethodid")
    def trxCashier = column[String]("trx_cashier")

    def * =
      (
        trxId,
        trxType,
        trxPatMethodId,
        trxCashier
      ) <> (Trx.tupled, Trx.unapply)

  }
}
```

La clase `TrxStateRepository` la cual es la única que se supone que debe acceder a la data de la base de datos para la tabla `TrxState`

```
@Singleton
class TrxStateRepository @Inject()(override val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
)(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)extends BaseRepository[TransactionStatus]
with QrApplicationErrorHandler with Logging {

  private val trxState = TableQuery[TransactionStatusTable]

  def getLastStatusForTrx(trxId: Long)(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext)
  : Future[TransactionStatus] = {
    trxState.filter(_.trxId === trxId).sortBy(_.sequence.desc).result.headOption
  }

  def getAllTrxState()(implicit mapMarkerContext: MapMarkerContext)
  : Future[Seq[TrxState]] = {
    logger.info(EnumLogger.LastStatusTxsForClosure.toString)
    val sequence = (trxState.map(_.sequence).max.asColumnOf[Int]).asColumnOf[Int]
    /*
    trxState.sortBy(_.sequence)
      .filter(trxStates => trxState.status === "open")
     */
    for {
      t1 <- trxState
      if !(trxState.filter(t2 => t1.trxId === t2.trxId).map(_.sequence).max)
    } yield t1
    /*
    db.run(sql"""SELECT ts.* FROM (
    SELECT cp.* FROM trxstate 
    WHERE cp.sequence = (SELECT MAX(sc.sequence) FROM trxstate sc WHERE sc.trx_id = cp.trx_id)
    ) ts WHERE ts.status = 'open'""".as(Seq[String]))
    */
  }

  private class TrxStateTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[TrxState](tag, "transaction_status") {

    def trxStateId: Rep[Long]      = column[Long]("trx_state_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def trxId: Rep[Long]            = column[Long]("trx_id")
    def sequence: Rep[Int]                  = column[Int]("sequence")
    def status: Rep[String]                 = column[String]("status")

    def * =
      (
        trsxStateId.?,
        trxId,
        sequence,
        status
      ) <> (TrxState.tupled, TrxState.unapply)
  }

}
```

`DTOLists` el cual es el DTO que se retornara

```
case class DTOLists(
  listOne: List[String],
  listTwo: List[Int]
)
```

Honestamente no pude crear la sentencia usando Slick, así que traté de harcodear la sentencia con Plain SQL para cada método, pero me generaba un error indicando siempre `Mismath Value` con el tipo de retorno.

¿Puede alguien por favor ayudarme con la creación de la consulta y los tipos de retorno de Slick para que hacer el join sea posible desde otros métodos? He intentado con `Query[]`, `Seq`, `TableQuery`, `Future[Seq[]]` pero sinceramente no pude resolver el problema con los tipos de retorno o la sentencia manejada como texto SQL.

Espero haber sido claro con la explicación y pido disculpas por la extensión de la pregunta, pero prefiero ser claro con todo así es posible ver el panorama completo.

De antemano muchas gracias

Posdata: De verdad quiero que mi código sea extensible y permita reusar el código.